# Serilog sink wrapper mapping, separate filename from content

Tags: c#, serilog

Using the [Serilog.Sinks.Map](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map) library, the example shows

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Map("Name", "Other", (name, wt) => wt.File($"./logs/log-{name}.txt"))
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("Hello, {Name}!", "Alice");
Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

An event written to `log-Alice.txt` with text `Hello, Alice!`

How do I do similar but separate the filename from the content? Eg I want to do

```
Log.Information("Hello!", "Alice");
```

which should write to a file `log-Alice.txt` but with text `Hello!`

Essentially my goal is to log to any named log but there could be hundreds of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Serilog.Sinks.Map`, in your example, is using a property called `Name` to define the file name. If you don't want to define this property in the message template, you can define it via `Context`, for example:

```
var log = Log.ForContext("Name", "Alice");

log.Information("Hello!");
log.Information("Hello Again!");
```

Both messages above would be written to the `log-Alice.txt` file, because they both carry a property `Name = "Alice"` in the log context.

Similarly, the below will write each message to a separate file:

```
Log.ForContext("Name", "John").Information("Hello 1!"); // log-John.txt
Log.ForContext("Name", "Peter").Information("Hello 2!"); // log-Peter.txt
```